# How do I get an embedded image into PNG format from a Microsoft Word File?

Tags: c#, ms-office, aspose

I have been using this code to extract image from word file:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Image.SampleImages.doc");

    NodeCollection shapes = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Shape, true, false);
    int imageIndex = 0;           
    foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
    {
        if (shape.HasImage)
        {
            string imageFileName = string.Format(
                "Image.ExportImages.{0} Out{1}", imageIndex, FileFormatUtil.ImageTypeToExtension(shape.ImageData.ImageType));
            shape.ImageData.Save(MyDir + imageFileName);
            imageIndex++;
        }
    }
```

The output format of image is .emf whereas I want to have it .png. Please tell me how above code can be used to get "PNG" format instead of EMF.

Comment: you should mention that you are using this: http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/aspose.words.drawing.shape.imagedata.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ImageType property of Aspose ImageData is the original format of the image and is not changed during saving. You should instead get an Image object from ImageData (using ToImage), and then save it in the desired format. I.e.:

```
        shape.ImageData.ToImage().Save(MyDir + imageIndex.ToString() + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```